# Как получить style width при его изменении?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, коллеги. Нужна ваша помощь.
Есть горизонтальный скрол

```
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 28.7554%;"></div>
```

когда я перемещаю ползунок меняется его width, как мне отследить изменение width? Т.е. когда width поменялся выходил `console.log(измененный width)`

Comment: Создайте на jsfiddle.net код. Хочется посмотреть на чудо скролл, где у ползунка меняется ширина при скролле.

Answer (score 0):

Для отслеживания изменения ширины элемента можно использовать событие [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend), которое срабатывает сразу после изменения свойства, но только в том случае, если у элемента был предусмотрено свойство transition

Код ниже демонстрирует работу с этим событием, но на примере свойства height

```js
let initHeight = 10
let currentHeight = initHeight
let slider = document.getElementById('slider')
let button = document.getElementById('button')

slider.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false);
button.addEventListener('click', setHeight)

slider.style.height = `${initHeight}px`

function setHeight() {
  slider.style.height = `${++currentHeight}px`
}

function showMessage () {
console.log(slider.style.height)
}
```

```css
#slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #8BC34A;
  transition: height 0.001s;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
<button id="button">Увеличить высоту</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.ui-slider-range').resize(function() { console.log('lalala') }
```

ну как-то так

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/   
Нет такого события. А для элементов тем более, кроме textarea, iframe, frame etc.

Comment: у вас есть элемент ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min и у него есть ширина, вы ее ползунком меняете, чем вам resize не угодил? https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: А вы попробуйте применить его к div

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft из документации: Description: Bind an event handler to the "resize" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Comment: Чем спорить, лучше показать https://jsfiddle.net/0u6b678a/